# Pyomo: change index of variable

Tags: variables, pyomo

after a couple of months, I built up an optimization approach of a bigger energy system.

Within this, I try to change the index of pyomo variables in order to recalculate the model within a loop.
With an older version of pyomo, that was possible by mdl.component.reconstruct(). But since (maybe) 2021, this function was removed.

Is there any other possibility to change the index of a variable? Or the possibility to delete and generate it again?

Best thanks in advance!
Mathias